# System cannot find the patch specified

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2012

I have a bat file that will execute every 10 minutes. On the cmd I see "The system cannot find the path specified".

Any ideas why?

Below is the code:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM SET DATA, TIME AND PATH

SET DPATH="C:\keepalive\logs\"
SET DATES=%DATE:~7,2%_%DATE:~4,2%_%DATE:~10,4%
SET TIMES=%TIME:~0,2%_%TIME:~3,2%_%TIME:~6,2%
SET DAT=%DPATH%%DATES%.log

REM PRINTING USERNAME
ECHO USER:%USERNAME% 1>>%DAT% 2>&1

ECHO %DATES%%TIMES% 1>>%DAT% 2>&1
ECHO ACCESS WEBSITE 1>>%DAT% 2>&1
START iexplore http://example.com/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx

ECHO WAITING FOR WEBSITE 1>>%DAT% 2>&1
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 20000 >NUL

ECHO CLOSING WEBSITE 1>>%DAT% 2>&1
taskkill /F /T /IM iexplore.exe

EXIT
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Dude, comment out "@echo off", change it to "echo on", and the .bat file will *TELL* you what filepath it can't find!  GUESS: iexplorer.  SOLUTION: once you turn "echo on" and verify it's "iexplorer", just give it the whole path, e.g. `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`.  Don't forget to use quotes (").

Comment: When you set `dpath`, you include quotes. Then your `dat` becomes `"C:\whatever\"logger.log`. Take out the quotes and add them to whenever you write to the file, ex. `echo hi 1>>"%dat%"`.

Comment: Also: consider substituting something lighter-weight than iexplore, like [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

- RLH already pointed out potential problems due to the locale-dependent date/time format in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34585393/5047996); also removing the `\` from the `DPATH` value makes perfect sense;
- your location of the quotation marks is hard to handle; I stongly recommend to always use this `set` syntax: `set "VAR=Value"`, so the quotes do not become part of the variable value; so there is one place where to put the quotes effectively: reading (expansion) of the variable value, like `"%VAR%"`; this is particularly helpful in case of concatenation `"%VAR%\item"`, so the entire expression is enclosed within `""`, and there are no disturbing quotes within the string value;
- you should read the `%DATE%` and the `%TIME%` values in the same line or block of code for them to reflect the same point of time; using two independent command lines running exactly at midnight, although extremely improbable, could lead to the case that `%DATE%` returns the previous day but `%TIME%` already returns the next day;
- I recommend to reverse the redirection syntax from `echo string 1>> "file.ext" 2>&1` to `1>> "file.ext" echo string` in order to avoid any leading spaces to be output to the file `file.ext` as well; for `echo` you do not need the `2>&1` part at all, because it does not output anything to the *STDERR* channel (`2`), but only to the *STDOUT* channel (`1`);
- to wait for a certain amount of time using `ping`, you should use an IP that always exists and use the 1 second pause interval between multiple echo requests, because guessing a non-existing IP could fail in case it exists somewhen in the future; so for waiting for `3` seconds, you need `4` echo requests to have 3 pause intervals: `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 4`;
- you should add a window title for the `start` command, so you will never run into problems when the command is enclosed within quotation marks, because `start` considers the first quoted item as title: `start "" command`;
- instead of `exit` you should state `exit /B`, because `exit /B` quits the batch script while `exit` terminates the containing `cmd` instance; it won't change anything when executed via task scheduler, but when debugging it might be really annoying when `cmd` is always closed;

Here is the fixed code:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM SET DATE, TIME AND PATH

SET "DPATH=C:\keepalive\logs"
SET "DATES=%DATE%" & SET "TIMES=%TIME%"
SET "DATES=%DATES:~6,4%_%DATES:~3,2%_%DATES:~0,2%"
SET "TIMES=%TIMES:~0,2%_%TIMES:~3,2%_%TIMES:~6,2%"
SET "DAT=%DPATH%\%DATES%.log"

REM PRINTING USERNAME
1>> "%DAT%" ECHO USER:%USERNAME%

1>> "%DAT%" ECHO %DATES%%TIMES%
1>> "%DAT%" ECHO ACCESS WEBSITE
START "" "iexplore" "http://example.com/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx"

1>> "%DAT%" ECHO WAITING FOR WEBSITE
> NUL PING 127.0.0.1 -n 21

1>> "%DAT%" ECHO CLOSING WEBSITE
taskkill /F /T /IM "iexplore.exe"

EXIT /B
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the below line of code

```
SET DATES=%DATE:~7,2%_%DATE:~4,2%_%DATE:~10,4%
```

To:

```
SET DATES=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
```

Comment: That is what I said in my post.  Your local format is different than whoever provided that manipulation you were originally using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your local date format may be different than mine and you are not getting what you want from manipulating the date variable.

Run this in a test batch file:

```
@echo off
SET DATES=%DATE:~7,2%_%DATE:~4,2%_%DATE:~10,4%
echo %DATES%
pause
```

Test by removing the %DATES% string from DAT.  Does that still generate the same errors? `SET DAT="%DPATH%\TestName.log"`

I suggest that you change where your double quotes are at.  Currently you have them around `SET DPATH="C:\keepalive\logs\"`.  It's safer to do the below in case you ever generate a complex path with the name (like a space in it):

```
SET DPATH=C:\keepalive\logs
SET DATES=%DATE:~7,2%_%DATE:~4,2%_%DATE:~10,4%
SET TIMES=%TIME:~0,2%_%TIME:~3,2%_%TIME:~6,2%
SET DAT="%DPATH%\%DATES%.log"
```

Also moving the "\" into the DAT string instead of including it with the DPATH string makes it easier to see and know it is correct.